# How to insert a quoted string in quoted command

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Here i need to give in wsl ubuntu a path like this

```
$ alias gdt="cd /mnt/c/users/Azad's/desktop"
```

but it didn't take this, how to approach for this to give Azad's in quoted line.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to escape the single quote like this:

```
alias gdt="cd /mnt/c/users/Azad\'s/desktop"
```

Usually this work in most of the cases.

Comment: That directory name is going to cause trouble until the end of time.